# Do the auras of multiple winterwights stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

For example, if I build an encounter with 3 [winterwights](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/winterwight) standing in range of the other two's aura, will they have an effective fast heal of 30?

Answer (score 6):

No. Bonuses/effects of the same kind [don't stack](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Stacking), and the exact same effect never does (by default, specific rules can override that). See also [Stacking Effects](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Combining-Magic-Effects).

Comment: Cool, thank you very much. Appreciate the quick reply.

Comment: But they do take 6d10 cold damage per turn if within the area of all 3 winterwights.

Answer (score 3):

No.

[Aura of Cold](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/undead/winterwight#TOC-Aura-of-Cold-Su-) says:

> Winterwights are surrounded by a 10-foot radius of deathly chill. Any creatures within this area during the winterwight’s turn takes 2d10 points of cold damage. All creatures of the cold subtype within this area (including the winterwight) are treated as having fast healing 10.

Each winterwight's aura will independently grant creatures with the cold subtype fast healing 10 (unless, of course, they already have better fast healing). The aura doesn't "increase the fast healing" of such creatures, just grants it.

Similarly, each winterwight's aura will independently deal 2d10 points of cold damage to any creature in range, so one unlucky creature could potentially take 24d10 cold damage (12 winterwights, 8 adjacent plus 4 at the "cardinal points" so that their auras overlap).